# Get the path of all files along with data in Spark Scala rdd/dataframe

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark

I have a directory which has 100+ sub directories. Each sub directory has one text file. I want to write a spark/scala code to append subdirectory name to each of the records in files inside it.

eg.

contains of /parent_dir/subdir1/file1->

```
abc|123

def|456
```

contains of /parent_dir/subdir2/file1 ->

```
ghi|789
```

contains of /parent_dir/subdir3/file1 ->

```
jkl|901
```

Desired output file->

```
abc|123|subdir1

def|456|subdir1

ghi|789|subdir2

jkl|901|subdir3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read as a `text` file and get the `path` of file as below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Test App")
  .master("local[1]")
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val data = spark.read.text("/parent_dir/*")
  .select(input_file_name().as("path"), $"value")
```

Now you get the data as dataframe that consist of `path` of file and `data` as

```
+--------------------------------+-------+
|path                            |value  |
+--------------------------------+-------+
|file:///parent_dir/subdir1/file1|abc|123|
|file:///parent_dir/subdir1/file1|def|456|
|file:///parent_dir/subdir3/file1|jkl|901|
|file:///parent_dir/subdir2/file1|ghi|789|
+--------------------------------+-------+
```

Now you can parse the path and get only the required directory.

Hope this helps!